# How can I get the .class value of an array of classes?

Tags: java, reflection

Let's say I have an object called `thisObject`, which may be an int, String, Object, etc., or an array of such classes.  I would like the resulting class to be stored in a `Class` variable called `thisObjectArrayClass`.

This won't compile, but will hopefully explain what I'm looking for:

```
switch(thisObject.class) {
    case int.class:
        int[] tempObject;
        thisObjectArrayClass = tempObject.class;
        break;
    case float.class:
        float[] tempObject;
        thisObjectArrayClass = tempObject.class;
        break;
    case int[].class:
        int[][] tempObject;
        thisObjectArrayClass = tempObject.class;
        break;
}
```

The problem with this is that it relies on a switch/case statement, which is obviously unacceptable.  My attempts to do this using reflection failed, but I'm new to Java, so perhaps I did something wrong.  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `Array.newInstance`:

```
thisObjectArrayClass = Array.newInstance(thisObject.class, 0).getClass();
```

This instantiates a *0-length* array of `thisObject.class`es, and requests the `class` of such object.

Comment: Bah... this is exactly what I tried, but I used `.class` instead of `.getClass()`.  I was so close.  :(

Comment: @Michael: `.class` is the _static class_ of the object, in this case `java.lang.Object`. `getClass()` is the _dynamic class_ of the object.

Comment: Using `thisObject.class` implies that `thisObject` is the literal name of the class, in which case the answer to the question would just be to use `thisObject[].class`. I suspect that `thisObject` is actually a reference variable, in which case to get the class of the object it points to, he would need to do `thisObject.getClass()`

Answer (score 1):

Object has a getClass() method.

```
public Class getClass(Object thisObject) {  
    Class thisObjectArrayClass = obj.getClass();  
    System.out.println("The type of the object is: " + thisObjectArrayClass.getName());  
    return thisObjectArrayClass;
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how that answers the question of getting a class object representing the class of an array of objects of the type of `thisObject`.

Answer (score -1):

You can only switch on integers (or Strings in Java7). Either use an if/else sequence or a switch in 7. Either way the method you are probably looking for is thisObject.getClass()

```
switch(obj.getClass().getName()) {
    case "java.lang.String" :
        System.out.println("Found String");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Found:" + obj.getClass().getName());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int array[] = new int[7];
array.getClass();
```